# Capistrano: cap deploy vs cap deploy:update

Tags: capistrano

What's the difference between `cap deploy` and `cap deploy:update`?

I assume the latter just does an update - any better insights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha - reading through the source ([`deploy.rb`](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb))

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc <<-DESC
    Deploys your project. This calls both `update' and `restart'. Note that \
    this will generally only work for applications that have already been deployed \
    once. For a "cold" deploy, you'll want to take a look at the `deploy:cold' \
    task, which handles the cold start specifically.
  DESC
  task :default do
    update
    restart
  end
```

So, `deploy` does a an `update` and then a `restart`.

`update` just performs an update on the server.

Answer (score 3):

Update adds a new release folder and changes the symlink, but does not restart. This is useful if you run migrations from the server. For example, we do not allow remote database access so to deploy with migrations, we use cap deploy:update, then log in to the server and run the migrations, then cap deploy:restart.

It can also be useful if you want background jobs, (e.g. cron jobs, not long-running daemons) to pick up new code changes without having to restart the web handlers.